# Extreme 210 fiber port not connecting

Tags: network, networking, fiber

Let me preface my question by saying I'm not a network admin and don't know nearly enough about networking.

I have an Extreme 210-12p-GE2 switch.

My problem is that the fiber port that was working is now not working. I had to temporarily disconnect the fiber as I was moving cables around to clean up the physical routing of the cables around the server rack. I have plugged it back in, but it isn't passing any signal through it.

I have figured out a little of the CLI commands and have found this information about the port:

```
(Extreme 210) #show fiber-ports optical-transceiver-info all

                         Link Link                                 Nominal
                       Length Length                                   Bit
                         50um 62.5um                                  Rate
Port     Vendor Name      [m] [m]  Serial Number    Part Number     [Mbps] Rev  Compliance
-------- ---------------- --- ---- ---------------- ---------------- ----- ---- ----------------
0/13     FORMERICAOE      0   0    20092-91732      TSD-S2CA1-F11M    1300      1000LX
```

So, it is showing that it is plugged in, but it's not passing any traffic or showing that it is active.
[image: Port Summary Port 0/13]

My questions are:

1. Did I break something when I disconnected the cable?
2. How do I get the switch to start passing traffic again?

**EDIT Adding Logs**

Event Log

[image: Event Log]

**EDIT adding fiber-port info**

```
(Extreme 210) (Interface 0/14)#show fiber-ports optical-transceiver all

                                    Output    Input
Port      Temp  Voltage  Current     Power    Power   TX     LOS
           [C]   [Volt]     [mA]     [dBm]    [dBm]   Fault
--------  ----  -------  -------   -------  -------   -----  ---
0/14      39.5    3.330     28.6    -5.962  -40.000   No     Yes
```

This last column, *LOS*, does that mean that the switch isn't sending a signal or that it isn't receiving a signal from the switch at the other end?

Comment: Have you tried swapping The two fibers of the fiber pair?

Comment: @TeunVink I didn't know I could do that. I will try and see what happens

Comment: @TeunVink I am not able to switch the two fibers in the pair. I cannot turn them over or separate them without breaking the plastic that holds them together. I tried moving them to the other fiber port, but still nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to seem dumb, but I finally got this working.

I had to go to the other end of the fiber cable. I found that it was the port on the other switch, also an Extreme 210 (210-24p-GE2), was in D-Disabled state.

I can find no way to reset the port other than rebooting the switch. So I made sure the config was saved and rebooted. When the switch came again all was good.

Answer (score 1):

With *Link Status* down and *Admin Mode* enabled, I'd say the cable is either not fitted correctly or damaged.

I'd try reseating the SFP module and replugging both ends. Check the cable for excessive bending (<10x diameter) or even kinks. Also check the jacks and end faces for any sign of dirt - they need to be immaculately clean. If that doesn't help try another cable.

You could also check for light on -SX/-SR modules (850 nm) using a digital camera, but that seems to be an -LX module where the wavelength (1310 nm) is out of a digicam's scope.

If there are multiple fiber patches and you might have mismatched the cable: you need to use a single-mode cable (usually with a yellow sleeve) with -LX. Orange, aqua or green cables indicating multi-mode fiber won't work.

Also, the endfaces of connector and terminal need to match: either UPC (blue or grey) or APC (green) are used with single-mode fiber. They cannot be mixed.

Comment: I tried pulling out the module and then disconnecting the fiber from it. Then I put the module back in, then reconnected the fiber to it, and made sure that everything is seated firmly. No change. I don't see any excessive bending or kinks. I don't have any other cables that I can try

Comment: Anything from the log?

Comment: What log? On the switch? What log would be helpful to see? There's an event log that has 45 entries, the most recent are errors with a code of 00000000 and file name of dma.c

Comment: Yes, the log from the switch that shuts down the port.

Comment: I don't get much from the logs. I have posted an update showing what is in the event log. Nothing that specifies either fiber ports